# Override to!T() for used-defined T in D?

Tags: type-conversion, d

I have structs and classes that I'd like to be able to easily create from strings in a generic fashion, using the `to!T(string)` method. However, I'm not sure how I could 'override' the method to get this kind of behavior. Going from my type to the string is easy (I would just define `opCast(string)`), but is what I'm looking for even possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't define an `opCast` for `string` if you want your type to convert to `string`. That's what `toString` is for. `writeln` and `format` and the like use `toString`, not casting or `to`, and `to` will use `toString`, so it's definitely better to define `toString` for converting to to `string`. You define `opCast` for converting to types *other* than `string`. Then you can use that with casting or with `to`.

Now, if you want to convert a `string` to your user-defined type, then just define the appropriate constructor, and that will work with `to`.

```
import std.conv;

struct S
{
    int i;

    this(string s)
    {
        i = to!int(s);
    }

    string toString()
    {
        return to!string(i);
    }
}

void main()
{
    auto s = to!S("42");
    assert(s.i == 42);
    auto t = to!string(s);
    assert(t == "42");
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, didn't realize it was that simple!